# Android: Context menu callback position off by one when ListView contains a header

Tags: android, listview, adapter

I have a ListView with a header, set using `ListView.addHeader(...)`
It appears to work just fine except when trying to create the context menu.

When the user long-presses a row, the position in the `onCreateContextMenu` callback seems to be off by one. When the user long-presses the header, the position reported is 0 (I wouldn't expect a callback), when the user long-presses the first row, the position reported is 1 instead of 0 and so on.

The same code works as expected without a header.

I know that internally Android just creates a new Adapter around mine when I set a header, but I would assume they handle adjusting the position before invoking callbacks.

Is what I'm seeing expected behavior? Am I doing something wrong, perhaps?

Here's how I fetch the position:

```
public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View v, ContextMenuInfo menuInfo) {
    AdapterView.AdapterContextMenuInfo info = (AdapterView.AdapterContextMenuInfo) menuInfo;
    int position = info.position;

    // this is my workaround, but I'm afraid it's going to bite me in
    // the ass if/when GOOG fixes this
    if( this.hasHeader() && position > 0 ) position--;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I know that internally Android just creates a new Adapter around mine when I set a header, but I would assume they handle adjusting the position before invoking callbacks.

I doubt it. I have not tried this specific behavior, but having written wrapping adapters myself, it's not a readily solvable problem.

Simply put, the context menu stuff does not involve the `Adapter` at all, only the `AdapterView`. Hence, there is no chance for a wrapping `Adapter` to either consume menu events or to adjust position values.

I suspect that you will simply need to subtract `1` and ignore the header row yourself.

Comment: Thanks. So `AdapterView` passes around position of _views_, but the Adapter actually passes around index values of the actual list items, regardless of whether the header is set or not? I think I understand what you're saying but it'll pacify my doubts if you know of any documentation that explains how setting header affects the position in AdapterContextMenuInfo objects. My search didn't yield anything about this specifically.

Comment: @psychotik: "So AdapterView passes around position of views, but the Adapter actually passes around index values of the actual list items, regardless of whether the header is set or not?" -- `AdapterView` thinks `position` will run from `0` to whatever the `Adapter` returns for `getCount()` minus `1`. Period. It is completely oblivious as to what that means. `ListView` replaces the `Adapter` with a different (wrapping) `Adapter`. The wrapping `Adapter` knows that position `0` is the header and `getCount()` must bump by `1`.

Comment: @psychotik: "if you know of any documentation that explains how setting header affects the position in AdapterContextMenuInfo objects" -- I doubt there is anything but the source code. You are welcome to examine `AdapterView`, `ListView`, and the wrapping `Adapter` class (some inner class of `ListView` IIRC, though it's been a while since I examined that behavior).